# Arcgis API for JS : change spatial reference of graphic layer

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api

I have an app with features layers and graphics layers which don't have the same spatial reference (i.e 102110 and 4326). 
My map has the same spatial reference as my features layers (102110).
I can't turn the spatial reference of my graphics layers (4326) into the one of my map and features layers.
Do you have any idea to help me ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GraphicsLayer` or `FeatureLayer` does not have any `SpatialReference` information in them. Spatial references are part of the geometry/graphic objects and Map also.

The SpatialReference of FeatureLayer matches with map:

> When requests are made for features from a service, the map's spatial
>   reference will be included which tells the service to re-project
>   features before sending them to the client.

Whereas, `GraphicsLayer` are maintained entirely within the application. The developer needs to ensure that projections match before adding the graphics on the map. To change the projection system, you can use `GeometryService`, below is a sample.

```
require(["dojo/_base/array", "esri/tasks/GeometryService", "esri/tasks/ProjectParameters", "esri/SpatialReference"], function(GeometryService, ProjectParameters, array) {
    var geometries = array.map(graphicsLayer.graphics, function(graphic){
        return graphic.geometry;
    });

    var gsvc = new GeometryService("https://utility.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

    var outSR = new SpatialReference({wkid:102110});

    var params = new ProjectParameters();
    params.geometries = geometries ;
    params.outSR = outSR;
    params.transformation = transformation;
    gsvc.project(params, function(projectedGeometries){
        for(var i = 0; i < projectedGeometries.length;i++){
            graphicsLayer.graphics[i].setGeometry(projectedGeometries[i]);
        }
    });

});
```